# Как позиционировать элементы при инициализации очередного слайда slick?

Tags: javascript, css, slider, позиционирование, slick.js

Есть `slick` слайдер где на каждом слайде есть по 2 абсолютно спозиционированных интерактивных элемента при клике на которые происходят определенные действия.

Проблема в том, что при переключении слайдов после последнего (фактически при инициализации слайдера заново), эти элементы позиционируются с задержкой и получается эффект их выпрыгивания их стартовой позиции на свои законные места (если повращать слайдер - это видно). В демо примере даже почему-то прибавляется белая область снизу.

Как инициализировать элементы заранее? [Фидл](https://jsfiddle.net/hibbard_eu/5ox31m2a/)

```js
$('.slider').slick({
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    dots: true,
    infinite: true
});
```

```css
.slider {
    width: 650px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
}
.slick-slide {
    position: relative;
}
#plus-1 {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 141px;
    right: 20%;
    width: 65px;
    height: 65px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#plus-2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 45%;
    left: 20%;
    width: 65px;
    height: 65px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.3.15/slick.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.3.15/slick.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="slider">
  <div>
    <img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png" />
        <img id="plus-1" class="plus-1" src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/classic-icons/512/063.png" width="65" height="65">
    <img id="plus-2" class="plus-1" src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/classic-icons/512/063.png" width="65" height="65">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz2.png" />
            <img id="plus-1" class="plus-1" src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/classic-icons/512/063.png" width="65" height="65">
    <img id="plus-2" class="plus-1" src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/classic-icons/512/063.png" width="65" height="65">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`id` может содрежать только уникальное значение, на странице должен находиться только один элемент с таким `id`. Для стилизации разных элементов используйте `class`.

```js
$('.slider').slick({
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  dots: true,
  infinite: true,

});
```

```css
.slider {
  width: 650px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.slider__item {
  position: relative;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
}

.slick-slide {
  position: relative;
}

.plus-1 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 141px;
  right: 20%;
  width: 65px;
  height: 65px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.plus-2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 45%;
  left: 20%;
  width: 65px;
  height: 65px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.3.15/slick.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.3.15/slick.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="slider">

  <div class="slider__item">
    <img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png" />
    <img class="plus-1" src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/classic-icons/512/063.png" width="65" height="65">
    <img class="plus-1 plus-2" src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/classic-icons/512/063.png" width="65" height="65">
  </div>
  <div class="slider__item">
    <img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz2.png" />
    <img class="plus-1" src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/classic-icons/512/063.png" width="65" height="65">
    <img class="plus-1 plus-2" src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/classic-icons/512/063.png" width="65" height="65">
  </div>
</div>
```